# Which tools or service to use for testing the site?

Tags: security

I have site and would like to test how it can resist hacker's attack like some kinds of injections, DDOS etc?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check out BackTrack, it's a security oriented linux distribution that comes with a miriad of differnt tools to attempt to penetrate your site's security.
http://www.backtrack-linux.org/
It's also an excellent tool to check general security on home/office networks.
Good luck!

EDIT: You might also want to check out: http://www.metasploit.com/ 
It's an excellent exploit fraimwork that will allow you to test and retest your server with everything you can possibly think of!

Comment: Thanks! Maybe something more?

Comment: I added a website above: http://www.metasploit.com/ It's a penetration testing exploit framework that should help you test your server. Good luck!

Comment: Also check out: http://www.rapid7.com/vulnerability-scanner.jsp If yo're ready to pay, their Enterprise solution is excellent.